# Php regex - Extracting sentences containing a string

Tags: php, regex

I have been looking at how regex works in php recently, and I had this idea to try to extract sentences from Wikipedia, if they contained a search term.
So far I managed to extract only sentences with this:

```
$content = $wdata->query->pages->$wpageid->extract; 
preg_match_all('/(?<=[.?!]|^).*?(?=([.?!])\s{0,3}[A-Z]|$)/s',$content,$matches);
echo "<pre>";
for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++)
$result[] = trim($matches[0][$i]).$matches[1][$i];
print_r($result);
```

I've managed to figure out how this works, and how to insert my string to filter... but, where ever I put it, It breaks the regex.

So, my string is $search, and my question; were do I put it in the regex, or how do I make it no only find sentences, but sentences with $search in them somewhere.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=[.?!]|^).*?(?=([.?!])\s{0,3}[A-Z]|$)/s',$content,$matches);

('.$search.')
```

**Edit:**

Ok, so I'm trying to use:

```
$content = $wdata->query->pages->$wpageid->extract; 
preg_match_all('/(?<=[.?!]|^).*?(?=([.?!])\s{0,3}[A-Z]|$)/s', $content, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    if (strpos($match, $search)) {
        print $match;
    }
}
```

But I get a blank page

Comment: maybe find all sentences and then exclude these without searched word.

Comment: Could I see some examples please, as I said, I'm quite new, lacking understanding of the inner workings

Comment: To exclude the ones without the searched word, would I use a foreach($result) { //contains $search //Doesn't } or something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

Robert is right. You must compare your `$string` to the relevant `$matches`...

For example, something like this:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    if ($match === $string) {
        print "$string found!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean a code example, the logic behind it, I'm not sure which variables go where :P

Comment: Try yourself some debugging thrill... :-) For example print $match before ther "if" condition...

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the regex Idea, I've tried every logical way of putting it together, but failed, I have also asked another question, hopefully it explains the problem more, as I think (Think...) that its to do with the actual regex pattern, putting $search somewhere in there in brackets: ('.$search.'). Thanks for your help, i'll keep it in case I suddenly realize what I'm doing wrong. :P Thanks!